How to fix UsePostgreSqlStorage is obsolete: 'Will be removed in 2.0. in Hangfire string connection?
The code snippet provided below is currently generating a warning:
builder.Services.AddHangfire(config => config
.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
.UsePostgreSqlStorage(defaultConnString));

The warning message is as follows:

'PostgreSqlBootstrapperConfigurationExtensions.UsePostgreSqlStorage(IGlobalConfiguration, string)' is obsolete: 'Will be removed in 2.0. Please use UsePostgreSqlStorage(Action) overload.'

The versions of the packages currently in use are:
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.8.12" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.PostgreSql" Version="1.20.8" />

Despite the warning, this is the only configuration that works for me. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

You can’t “fix” something that’s going to be removed. You can either stick on the version you have forever, or change your code to use UsePostgreSqlStorage(Action) as suggested in the warning.

Yeah your comment really helped me out...

I've tried to set up Hangfire with the corrected configuration. Still gives me an error:
builder.Services.AddHangfire(config => config
.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
.UsePostgreSqlStorage(options =>
{
options.ConnectionString = connString;
}));

The same error?

No, different:
'PostgreSqlBootstrapperOptions' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectionString' and no accessible extension method 'ConnectionString' accepting a first argument of type 'PostgreSqlBootstrapperOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

services.AddHangfire(config =>     config.UsePostgreSqlStorage(c =>         c.UseNpgsqlConnection(connectionString))

Thanks to stuartd point in a right direction.
It appears that the UseNpgsqlConnection method is a valid method within the PostgreSqlStorageOptions class in my version of Hangfire. This method is likely a convenience method provided by the Hangfire.PostgreSql extension to simplify the configuration of the PostgreSQL storage.
Working code without a warning:
builder.Services.AddHangfire(config => config
.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
.UsePostgreSqlStorage(options => options.UseNpgsqlConnection(connString)));

